# C: issue with printing an array of char *

Tags: c, arrays

I have an array of char * initialized like this:

```
char *keys[16]; //16 elements, each of which is a char *
```

Then I am assigning to this array like this:

```
  for(i = 0; i < NUM_ROUNDS; i++)
  {
     //do some operations that generate a char* holding 48 characters named keyi
     keys[i] = keyi;
  }
```

But then when I printout all of the elements of the char * array I am getting junk at the end of the print statement:

```
  int k;
  for(k = 0; k < 16; k++)
  {
     printf("keys[%d] = %s\n", k,keys[k]);
  }
```

Output looks like this:

```
keys[0] = 000110110000001011101111111111000111000001110010çVTz¸ä
keys[1] = 011110011010111011011001110110111100100111100101çVTz¸ä
keys[2] = 010101011111110010001010010000101100111110011001çVTz¸ä
keys[3] = 011100101010110111010110110110110011010100011101çVTz¸ä
keys[4] = 011111001110110000000111111010110101001110101000çVTz¸ä
keys[5] = 011000111010010100111110010100000111101100101111çVTz¸ä
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here? Should I be allocating memory before assigning to the array ?

Comment: What is `keyi` ? Where do you get it from ?

Comment: have you checked whether `keyi` is properly NULL terminated or not?

Comment: Do your individual strings have null-terminator characters?

Comment: The "//do some operations that generate a char* holding 48 characters named keyi"  is quite likely your culprit here, you need to show that code.

Comment: `keyi` is a `char *` that I generate by doing a bunch of array concatenation and compression, which I abstracted here because it isn't relevant. Thank you for the null terminated mention, that `\0` always gets me..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems most likely that `keyi` isn't NUL-terminated.

Maybe you want this ?

```
keyi[48] = 0;   /* Caveat, keyi must be at least 49 chars wide. */
keys[i] = keyi;
```

Or maybe:

```
printf("keys[%d] = %.48s\n", k,keys[k]);
```

Comment: Thanks, coming from Java that `\0` always gets me :|

Answer (score 2):

`%s` prints the contents untill it encounters a `\0`, Your elements are not `\0` terminated.
So it prints out the contents until it randomly encounters a `\0`.

You should explicitly `\0` terminate your contents.

Answer (score 1):

You should write a `0` byte onto the end of the 48 character string, or it won't know when to stop printing. Just be sure to allocate 49 bytes to allow for this.

Answer (score 1):

Your `char*`s do not point to NUL-terminated strings. You need to make `keyi` 49 bytes long, and put a 0 at `keyi[48]`.